# Export-AzureVM is not creating the file

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am having trouble getting Export-AzureVM to work.

Here is my output:

---

PS C:\Users\jason_000\documents\azuresp2013> .\export

VERBOSE: 9:44:23 AM - Begin Operation: Get Deployment

VERBOSE: 9:44:24 AM - Begin Operation: Get Deployment

VERBOSE: 9:44:24 AM - Begin Operation: Get Deployment

VERBOSE: 9:44:25 AM - Begin Operation: Get Deployment

VERBOSE: 9:44:26 AM - Begin Operation: Get Deployment

VERBOSE: 9:44:27 AM - Begin Operation: Get Deployment

---

My export.ps1 script is as follows:

```
Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName vmsp01-jdevsp28102656 -Name vmsp01
$ExportPath = "C:\ExportVMs\ExportAzureVM-vmsp01.xml" 
Export-AzureVM -ServiceName vmsp01-jdevsp28102656 -name vmsp01 -Path $ExportPath 
Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName vmdb01-jdevsp28102656 -Name vmdb01 
$ExportPath = "C:\ExportVMs\ExportAzureVM-vmdb01.xml" 
Export-AzureVM -ServiceName vmdb01-jdevsp28102656 -name vmdb01 -Path $ExportPath 
Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName vmad01-jdevsp28102656 -Name vmad01 
$ExportPath = "C:\ExportVMs\ExportAzureVM-vmad01.xml" 
Export-AzureVM -ServiceName vmad01-jdevsp28102656 -name vmad01 -Path $ExportPath
```

The file path C:\ExportVMs exists.

My virtual machine names are vmad01, vmdb01, and vmsp01

I have 3 cloud services in my account whose names are vmad01-jdevsp28102656,vmdb01-jdevsp28102656 and vmsp01-jdevsp28102656

The script runs real quick and just drops back to the prompt, but there is nothing in the C:\ExportVMs folder when complete.

Thanks for your time,

Jason

Answer (score 1):

Is that a snippet of the full script or all of it? You need to make sure to do the setup first to connect to your subscription before executing the commands. (And import the Azure module before this)

Such as:

```
Import-Module Azure

# Connect to Azure subscription

$subsciprtionName = "<Name>"
$subscriptionID = "<Subscription ID>"
$certThumbprint = "<Certificate thumbprint>"
$storateAccountName = "<Storage account name>"

$cert = Get-Item Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$certThumbprint
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subsciprtionName -SubscriptionId $subscriptionID -Certificate $cert
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subsciprtionName
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subsciprtionName -CurrentStorageAccount $storateAccountName
```

I tested a run of this on my setup. You should get a result with OperationStatus Succeeded. The output is an XML file about 2KB in size for my test VMs (this command only exports the VM configuration, not the disks themselves). Because of this, you don't need to shut down the VM before exporting its configuration with this command. My result:

```
PS C:\Users\Noah> Export-AzureVM -Path C:\Images\WEB1-state.xml -ServiceName perceptenWEB1 -Name WEB1


DeploymentName        : WEB1
Name                  : WEB1
Label                 : 
VM                    : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.ServiceManagement.Model.PersistentVM
InstanceStatus        : StoppedVM
IpAddress             : 10.215.74.54
InstanceStateDetails  : 
PowerState            : Stopped
InstanceErrorCode     : 
InstanceFaultDomain   : 0
InstanceName          : WEB1
InstanceUpgradeDomain : 0
InstanceSize          : Small
AvailabilitySetName   : 
DNSName               : http://perceptenweb1.cloudapp.net/
ServiceName           : perceptenWEB1
OperationDescription  : Export-AzureVM
OperationId           : 584b719c-c1a9-4747-a41b-2609f77de2e8
OperationStatus       : Succeeded
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your assistance. It turns out that I had been using the wrong servicename.

For anyone else that comes along, To check if you are doing the same-

Run Get-AzureVM with no parameters to verify it is returning the VM that way, and to confirm the ServiceName and Name for the VM you are trying to export.

Get-AzureVM

Then run Get-AzureVM to show that specific VM:

Get-AzureVM -ServiceName  -Name

And if that works, pipe that into Export-AzureVM:

Get-AzureVM -ServiceName  -Name  | Export-AzureVM -Path C:\ExportVMs\vm.xml

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Hopefully Microsoft adds a thrown exception when the names are incorrect.